# If two graphs have same Laplacian spectrums, are they the similar graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

If graph A and graph B have exactly the same Laplacian spectrums, can I just say they are same graphs? (only with scaling edge weights and node index reordering) I don't know if there is any explicit definition of graph similarity.

And the reverse question could be: if two graph are similar in the sense that they only have reordered node index, or edge weight scaling, do they have same Laplacian spectrums?

Comment: Can you hear the shape of a graph?

Comment: It might help you to look up "cospectral graphs" and maybe also "Godsil-McKay switching".

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found following statements:"Nonisomorphic graphs with the same spectrum are cospectral, and they are called cospectral mates."

Comment: I find this paper which is very helpful: http://arno.uvt.nl/show.cgi?fid=59786

Comment: @gerry-myerson: Are you talking about this paper? http://iopscience.iop.org/0305-4470/34/31/301/pdf/0305-4470_34_31_301.pdf

Comment: No, I wasn't aware of that paper; I had in mind the Kac paper that paper refers to, the famous paper about hearing the shape of a drum.